# How to install kcbench on a computer without internet？

Tags: linux, software-installation, benchmark

I want to install `kcbench` on the Linux server I use. The server is not connected to the Internet, but my computer (window) is able to connect to the Internet, and I can connect to the server via ssh. How can I use my computer to help install `kcbench` on the server?

https://linux.die.net/man/1/kcbench

https://gitlab.com/knurd42/kcbench

This is the related website I found.

The above website describes how to install. It provides a script `kcbench`. If I have a network, I can install it directly with `bash kcbench`. But the server cannot access that website? Is there any way to assist the installation through my own computer? For example, my computer downloads it first, and then uploads it to the server? But according to the description of the above website, the script will be installed in some specific directories. Is there any way I can achieve the same result as running the script directly?
This is very important to me and I am very grateful to anyone who can provide advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the location of the download command in the script and comment it out. Download it on your computer and upload it to the folder indicated in the corresponding script on the server. Then continue to run the script.